# how to sort and join two files based on First Column Id

Tags: r, bash, linux

I have got two files large files like this in Tab-delimited format, trying to merge in R, do we need to sort the file before merging?

```
 otu <- read.table("asv.txt", sep="\t", header=T, blank.lines.skip=F, check.names=F)
> head(otu)
                ID                   Soil.9.S42 Soil-27.S33.L001 Soil-45.S54.L001
1 d2ec9f3b77975c0f457e4b7413b217ff         34               51               84
2 3147790f0d5a78316fb9dd64f53b9473         28               32               52
3 97aecc1f35cc1f50db507ad71dd22367         33                0                7
4 bfad6370d28182cc6304844e9bec7fb6        545              237              127
5 5fa2a987221a1d9ca416148570c18086          0                0                0
6 8e60d301122d7aa359eb6b0b00f37f62        124              143              128


> taxa <- read.table("taxonomy.txt", sep="\t", header=F ,stringsAsFactors=F,quote="")
> head(taxa)
                  ID                     V2             V3                  V4
d2ec9f3b77975c0f457e4b7413b217ff Bacteria  Cyanobacteria    Oxyphotobacteria
3147790f0d5a78316fb9dd64f53b9473 Bacteria Proteobacteria Alphaproteobacteria
97aecc1f35cc1f50db507ad71dd22367 Bacteria Proteobacteria Gammaproteobacteria
bfad6370d28182cc6304844e9bec7fb6 Bacteria Proteobacteria Alphaproteobacteria
5fa2a987221a1d9ca416148570c18086 Bacteria Proteobacteria Alphaproteobacteria
8e60d301122d7aa359eb6b0b00f37f62 Bacteria Proteobacteria Deltaproteobacteria
```

Now having issue with sorting file but merge command work perfectly;

```
newotu <- otu[order(ID),]
Error in order(ID) : object 'ID' not found
> total <- merge(otu,taxa,by="ID")
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean 'it didn't work'?

Comment: Also I'm confused - you seem to be reading the files into R and then using unix commands to merge? I prefer to do this sort of things in R - this should help https://www.statmethods.net/management/merging.html

Comment: I just use R showing the file content but wanted to do using unix command or R command.

Comment: OK - it's better to try in R IMO. Did you try follow the link I posted?

Comment: Error while doing in R, updated the command and error in the post.

Comment: Do we need to sort file in R before merging?

Comment: There was some issue with the command like header True or False, now fix it and trying again, but do we need to sort the file in R before merging?

Comment: no issue now while merging but when trying to sort file it shows error;

Comment: it doesn't need to be sorted

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. this is a very easy way to merge files in R. I also checked the file and it merges perfectly.

Comment: @user438383 or bioinfonext could one of you please post an answer with the solution you found so this question can be marked as answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check `left_join()` method in `dplyr` package. In this way you do not need to sort the data frames, as the function automatically take care of this.
For example: `merged_df <- left_join(otu, taxa, by = "ID")`.